# Snow Leopard Show Contents of VPN

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, osx-snow-leopard

I got the credentials to connect to my company's VPN from home. I'm running Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Problem is I can connect to the VPN, but no remote Volume appears in the Finder. I've tried in Finder selecting `Connect to Server` and entering `smb://domainname.com` and `afp://domainname.com` but I get this error

`The server “domainname.com” may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.`

Is there another way to view the remote Volume, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"domainname.com" is the domain name.  You need to specify the host name of the computer on the domain you want to access.  ie: `servername.domainname.com`.

That's assuming you work's IT have DNS setup properly for use with the VPN.  If not, then (once connected to via the VPN) you should be able to use the server's LAN IP address to access it instead.

For specific help with computer names and IPs, etc. at work, you'll have to speak with you company's IT support staff.

Comment: The server name is "Server01", so I entered server01.domainname.com using smb and afp, but was unable to connect.

Comment: Again, that'll only work if DNS redirection has been (properly) implemented for the VPN; does it work if you use the server's LAN IP address?  Also, you should be able to use [`nslookup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nslookup.1.html) to figure out if your current DNS configuration will resolve the name or not, if not, discuss it with your company's IT, as something's not configured properly then.

Comment: The IP address worked. My co-worker changed it and with the new one I was able to connect.